# Prove that running time $T(n) = n^3 + 20n \space \space \text{is}\space \space Ω(n^2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

> Prove that running time $T(n) = n^3 + 20n \space \space \text{is}\space \space Ω(n^2)$

#### My attempt:

This question is given on this [PDF(que-4)](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci220s1t/lectures/lecturenotes/GG-lectures/BigOhexamples.pdf).

I have understood the big-oh notation and it's conditions. I understood the given examples of bog-oh on given Pdf.

My question is:

> Why numerator has $n$ in $n + \cfrac{20}{n}\geq c$, and how they calculated: The left side of this inequality has the minimum value of $8.94$ for $n = \sqrt{20} ≅ 4.47$

Comment: This sentence "Is it necessary to $n$ in numerator with any power for $\Omega$" makes no sense to me.  It appears that the first part of the sentence is missing a verb (necessary to have $n$ do what?). What are powers of $\Omega$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is trying to explain the linked solution.  This is not the most efficient way to prove the desired relationship (see the comments for more efficient ways to prove this).

Starting with the desired inequality 
$$
n^3+20n\geq cn^2,
$$
they divide both sides by $n^2$ to get 
$$
\frac{n^3}{n^2}+\frac{20n}{n^2}\geq c.
$$
Simplifying, the result is
$$
n+\frac{20}{n}\geq c.
$$
Next, they use calculus to minimize the function 
$$
f(x)=x+\frac{20}{x}.
$$
Since
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{20}{x^2},
$$
$f$ has a local extrema at $x=\sqrt{20}$.  This can be seen to be a minimum by considering the signs of $f'$.  Therefore, the smallest that $f(x)$ can be is $2\sqrt{20}$.  Therefore, for all $n$,
$$
n+\frac{20}{n}\geq 2\sqrt{20}.
$$
Therefore, $2\sqrt{20}$ is a good choice for $c$ to make
$$
n^3+20n\geq 2\sqrt{20}n^2
$$
always true.

Note that the inequality $n+\frac{20}{n}\geq c$ can be dealt with in a much simpler way by observing that $n+\frac{20}{n}\geq n$ and since we're dealing with $n\geq 1$, $n+\frac{20}{n}\geq n\geq 1$.  The solution of interest gives a larger $c$ (so a "tighter bound"), but all that matters is that there is a $c$.

Comment: And almost none of this is necessary to show that $T(n)=n^3+20n$ is $\Omega(n^2)$ since, for every positive $n$, $T(n)\geqslant n^3=n\cdot n^2\geqslant n^2$.

Comment: Thanks. How you get $2\sqrt{20}?$

Comment: @Did I'm trying to add more details to the linked solution.  Of course it can be done more simply.

Comment: $f(\sqrt{20})=\sqrt{20}+\frac{20}{\sqrt{20}}=\sqrt{20}+\frac{\sqrt{20}\cdot\sqrt{20}}{\sqrt{20}}=\sqrt{20}+\sqrt{20}$.

Comment: A proeminent part of your answer should be that the little play with $2\sqrt{20}$ is squarely offtopic to solve the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, thanks.

Comment: @Did, lol. Actually, Still, why we follow this procedure? I need a reference regarding big-omega.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay "Still, why we follow this procedure?" Do we? I do not and will not, actually I find the solution suggested in the PDF you link to, rather mediocre, focusing on irrelevant aspects of the problem, and not clear enough about the direction of the implications it uses. It is sloppy work, especially in a pedagogical context.

Comment: @Did I added a few comments to highlight your concerns.  I also agree that the linked PDF is not a great way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Did, ok. Thanks.